# How to successfully prevent advance persistent threats

Tags: malware, antivirus, antimalware, apt

With the topic of advance persistent threats (APT) getting common nowadays, how do you successfully prevent such an attack in the workplace? Do you have to purchase expensive tools, such as those from Fireeye, which provide sandbox environments, or can we just use simple tools such as network sniffers to detect abnormal traffic and stop them going out of the network at the firewalls? What about endpoints? Is application whitelisting sufficient?

Comment: an APT is not an attack, but a threat - you can't prevent threats

Comment: Best practices can keep you safer and make it a lot harder for APT entities to get into your system, but imho if something as sophisticated and well-funded as an APT goes after any business, chances are they will get in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Advanced Persistent Threats" (APT) are primarily marketing language which  still has a true core. Lets analyze first the particular words to get to the core:

- Threat: This means it is somehow dangerous for you, so that you will be scared and buy something in the hope it will protect you. Note that when you are scared critical thinking often is reduced so you might buy anything just because of the marketing and not because of the true capabilities.
- Persistent: Attacker plans to have you infiltrated as long as possible. This might be the case because the attackers want to get as much as possible internal information from you, i.e espionage. Or they want to infiltrate your internal networks so that they will be able to disrupt critical processes at the right time, i.e sabotage. Or they want use you as a trampoline to hide attacks against other companies, by misusing existing trust relationships. Or something different.
- Advanced: This just means whatever you use currently will not work to detect the attack. This is another way of selling you something new, often marketed as "Advanced Threat Protection" (ATP). The similarity between APT and ATP might be intentional but is misleading. In my eyes "Advanced Threat Protection" is just the new buzzword because everybody now claims to have a "Next Generation Firewall" and the marketing needed something new. So it is mostly the same with a different name. And it still can be trivially bypassed as I've seen in [my research](http://noxxi.de/research/http-evader.html).

Thus at the end there is not much technical substance in the phrase "Advanced Persistent Threats", i.e. nothing which could suggest a specific solution. The main message of this phrase is that there is something unknown and dangerous where the current protection does not work and you need new one. But the "persistent" part at least tells you that you should assume that the attacker made it into your network, which means filtering at the perimeter is not enough. That's why a large part of the new products they sell are "Breach Detection Systems" (BDS) which are sold to help you in detecting and fighting existing infections.

There is no full protection against APT, same as there is no full protection against "regular" attacks. Thus at the end you want to reduce your risk to a level acceptable to you and only spend an acceptable amount of money and other resources to reduce the risk.  I suggest that you look closer at least at the following parts:

## Evaluate your risks

Before you can protect something you must know what to protect. Then you have to put a value on it because it makes no sense to spend more resources on protecting something than it is worth. You also need to analyze the existing attack vectors. Only after an exhaustive risk evaluation you know how much money you should be willing to spend and how to use these money in the optimal way.

Also note that if environments change the risks change too, so you need to reevaluate the risks from time to time.

## Reduce the chance to get infected at all

Once the attacker is inside the network it is much harder to get rid of the infection, because the attacker tries to behave as stealth as possible to keep persistence. Thus the best thing would be to make sure that you get not infected in the first place.

This means use of classical products like antivirus and deep inspection firewalls, web- and mail gateways ... This also means allowing only known good things, i.e. URL white lists, only executed signed code, only allow specific innocent kinds of mail attachments.. . While white listing is nice it is often impossible so at least have good black lists but be aware that they don't cover everything. And it means that potentially infected devices should be denied, i.e. no USB sticks, no BYOD (bring your own device) etc.

Awareness of the problems is absolutely important. This means lots training. Users with less awareness should work in a more restricted environments so that they can not cause that much damage. This often includes less tech savvy users like you will find in marketing and management. But even more knowledgeable users will be affected if the stress level increases. Thus an environment where users will get enough time to think about the problem is important too.

And of course malicious internal users can spoil any protection. Thus you should create an environment where users feel good but where they also notify you about potentially dangerous behavior of others.

## Detect successful infections early

There will be a time when an infections makes it into the network undetected. Thus you need to monitor your network for abnormal behavior. This can be Command and Control connections from the malware to its masters. It can be access to sensitive files by users which should not access these files. It can be abnormal times when users access systems etc. You can also plant canaries (special user accounts, special documents...) in the network and monitor their usage.

The most important part for a successful monitoring of the network for abnormal behavior is that you know what normal behavior should look like. Otherwise it is easy for an attacker to blend into the normal network activities.

Awareness of the users is also important for this part. Users should be aware that the network might be infected and thus not fully trust it. If they see something strange they should feel comfortable in reporting at, i.e. they should be thanked for their awareness even if it was a false positive this time.

## Reduce the impact of successful infections

You will not be able to find existing infections fast or even at all.  Typical APT attacks range from month to years before they get detected. Thus you must be sure that it is hard for an attacker to get to the core assets even if the attacker is inside your network. Therefore you should implement defense in depth. This includes segmenting your network into different security levels (guest network, developer network, marketing...) and reduce and monitor communication between these networks. It includes access control lists to files, which of course needs a proper user and permission management so that a user only has access to critical data as long as they are needed by the user etc.

## Summary

Buying products will help, but only after you have evaluated your risk so that you know what you need for optimal protection. There are companies which help you asking the right questions and these should probably not the same companies which  create the products. Independent resellers of multiple competing products might be better in helping you with an evaluation, because they are not committed in selling a specific product.

There are lots of important things outside buying products, like training and the right working environment. These too should be part of the risk evaluation and of the implemented solutions.

Answer (score 2):

I'll try to address several questions raised here.

It's not possible to prevent well-organized bad actors in the sense that we cannot create perfect computer security. Fundamentally the bugs will always come out before the fixes and we cannot invest an infinite amount of resources to protect all of our data. Therefore there will always be risk of some form in the system and the "cat & mouse" game of attackers and defenders will go on indefinitely.

That said there are many steps which can be taken to increase the likelihood of detection and also preventative steps which make it harder for a bad actor to penetrate an organization. None of these "require" expensive commercial tools and in many of the most secure organizations massive amounts of the security tooling are based on free-tools and free "big data" databases. At the time of this writing security automation is becoming a big deal and in a lot of cases using open-source tools provides a big advantage over many traditional computer security tools so the license and price of the tools themselves are not a restriction or issue security-wise.

If you take a step back abstraction-wise you can look at all the security controls you may need for a particular set of systems and find/deploy/develop really good security controls using free tools. This in itself is not an economic disadvantage. Unfortunately to deploy all of this correctly it would take a significant amount of work which usually is expensive at least in terms of labor.

In regard to what the industry calls apt attacks one thing that does seem to help that was not part of traditional computer security models is rebuilding the systems frequently from scratch. This fits into a DevOps or cloud deployment model well but neither of those are requirements.

Ultimately you want to have a lot of discipline in how your environment operates and this requires a lot of effort but we are constantly building systems which make this easier. There is a lot of room for improvement here in almost all organizations.

Whitelisting will never be sufficient as attackers will ultimately take control of one of the systems you have whitelisted. This is a huge problem for large companies with lots of smaller vendors. That said blacklisting and whitelisting are very valuable tools, use them well and wisely.

Answer (score 2):

That's a big, big topic area to cover. If I had to try to start to answer that in my own professional situation (I don't work day-in-day out with clients who need to defend against advanced threats in mass), I would start by looking at resources like the NSA's Information Assurance [mitigation guidance page](https://www.nsa.gov/ia/mitigation_guidance/index.shtml), which contains a lot of good guidance about defending against high-end threats*. [CERT's](https://www.us-cert.gov/) guidance, bulletins, and alerts are great for both learning about defending against specific attack methods of all kinds and keeping fully in touch with new threat developments. And there are other good sources out there that will talk about specific technical points related to defending against attacks used by sophisticated actors. Including, of course, this forum.

In terms of saying something myself about prioritizing where resources should get invested, based on what I've learned in the relatively short time I've been seriously studying and thinking about information security I'll just say this:

An organization that has really talented people--and enough of them--in their cybersecurity operations, along with good-but-not-"cutting edge" technology, will outperform one that has big-sticker, sparkling new security toys (from vendors who made extravagant promises about their capabilities) but not enough good people to use them well.  Almost every single. time. And against all classes of threat.

(*Whatever you think about the NSA's other ...activities, their Information Assurance stuff is well worth study.)